# List-Comprehension in Erlang - Variable unbound in guard

Tags: filter, erlang, list-comprehension

I am trying to build a list recursively with this method. OL (occurence list of characters) is a list that will eventually shrink to []. I need to use Q in the guard to check if the item can be subtracted. Basically it shall produce a filtered cartesian product.

```
b([[]], _)->[[]];
b(_, [])-> [[]];
b(OL, Keys)->[Y++[Q] || Y <- b(subtract(Q,OL), Keys),  Q <-Keys, len(subtract(Q,OL)) < len(OL)].
```

But i get the error:

> variable 'Q' is unbound

**Is there any way to use its value at that place?**

The subtract-method filters characters out of another list. 
subtract([{$a,1}],[{$a, 5},{$b, 1}]) returns [{$a, 5},{$b, 1}].

len() sums up the integer values of each tuple.
len([{$a, 5},{$b, 1}]) returns 6.

Comment: Could you also provide an example of how your function b will transform input to output like you did for subtract and b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put Q generator before its usage in Y generator. I guess the definitions are applied from left to right so when Y is applied there is no Q defined.

Comment: Could you give me an example how to write that? Thanks!